# Django: limit_choices_to (Is this correct)

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

Is this correct?

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)


class Order(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, limit_choices_to={'account': 'self.account'})
```

I'm trying to make sure that an Order form will only display customer choices that belong to the same account as the Order.

If I'm overlooking some glaring bad-design fallacy, let me know.

The main thing I'm concerned with is:

```
limit_choices_to={'account': 'self.account'}
```

Comment: Did not understand your question. Could you be more clear?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The only answer to 'is it correct' is 'does it work when you run it?' The answer to that of course is no, so I don't know why you're asking here.

There's no way to use limit_choices_to dynamically to limit based on the value of another field in the current model. The best way to do this is by customising the form. Define a ModelForm subclass, and override the `__init__` method:

```
class MyOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyOrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'initial' in kwargs:
             self.fields['customer'].queryset = Customer.objects.filter(account=initial.account)
```

Comment: Just because it didn't work for me didn't mean it had to be the wrong approach. I asked because there isn't clear documentation about this feature on the Django site, and I wasn't sure if my syntax was correct.

Comment: This is also good if you need to have request obj in class MyOrderForm -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/6062628/758202

Comment: Yes, this is not very clear in the docs. I suppose the problem is that `limit_choices_to` is a parameter of the ForeignKey function, and that function must be assigned to a class member. At this level, `self` means nothing. To make it working, `Django` should have a filter function that works in `__init__`, and, for what I know, it hasn't one.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `choices` field of your order form (inherited from `ModelForm`) in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with these functions in views.py where volumeSets is a many-to-many field. The form does not validate though. (Django 4.2) I am retrieving the posted values with:

```
        profile = request.user.profile
        formData = request.POST.items()
        for key, value in formData:
            if key == 'volumeSets':
                volumeSetIndex = int(value) - 1
                volumeSet = profile.volumeSets.all()[volumeSetIndex]
            elif key == 'volumeType':
                volumeType = int(value)




def setProfileFormInitial(formProfile, profile):
    '''
    This method sets the initial values for the choices of the profile form.
    :param formProfile: form for the Profile model
    :param profile: Profile model
    '''
    formProfile.initial = {
        "volumeSets":int(profile.volumeSetChoiceSelected),
        "volumeType":profile.volumeTypeChoiceSelected
    }


def createProfileForm(profile):
    '''
    This method creates a profile form.
    :param profile: Profile model
    :returns: Profile form
    '''                
    formProfile = ProfileEditForm()
    field = formProfile.fields["volumeSets"]
    field.queryset = profile.volumeSets.all()
    setProfileFormInitial(formProfile, profile)
    return formProfile
```

Answer (score -2):

`limit_choices_to={'account': 'self.account'}` is wrong, since foreign key to customer cannot point to `Account`.

Comment: Customer has "account" attribute though. Still this is the case?