# Django: limit_choices_to

Tags: django-models, foreign-keys

My question is same as
[Django: limit_choices_to (Is this correct)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968596/django-limit-choices-to-is-this-correct)

```py
class Customer(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)


class Order(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, limit_choices_to={'account': 'self.account'})
```

So, how to use the self here?
Is it really impossible to  use limit_choices_to dynamically to limit based on the value of another field in the current model?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a Django custom model method property in order\_by()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981375/using-a-django-custom-model-method-property-in-order-by)

Comment: So yeah can't we use limit_choices_to?