# Limit choices inside an input django

Tags: django, forms, limit

I am currently trying to improve my form by restricting choices inside an input (user can choose only their own tags).

[image]
tag name / user name

I tried to do that inside the get/post function :

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = DateInputForm(request.POST, limit_choices_to={'tags__user': request.user})

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = DateInputForm(limit_choices_to={'tags__user': request.user})
```

(1) I get an error.

> BaseModelForm.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'limit_choices_to'

My form :

```
class DateInputForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        # exclude = ('user',)
        fields = ['user', 'title', 'description', 'date_to_do', 'complete', 'tags']
        widgets = {
            'date_to_do': forms.DateTimeInput(format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M',
                                              attrs={'type': 'datetime-local', 'class': 'timepicker'}),
        }
```

My view :

```
class TaskUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Task
    template_name = "tasks/task_form.html"
    form_class = DateInputForm
```

Tag model :

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False, default='')
```

**Globally:** the goal is to limit the tags that can be chosen by the user in my task form (with the tag input); currently, a user can choose another user's tag, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to override the constructor of your form, as shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1969081/18728725

**Update:**
Here is Wamz's solution:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DateInputForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'instance' in kwargs:
            new_kwargs = kwargs.get('instance')
            self.fields['tags'].queryset = Tag.objects.filter(user=new_kwargs.user.id)
```

**Warning, that's not working in the createView**