# Django: Access request object from admin's form.clean()

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

My question is very similar to this one: [How do I access the request object or any other variable in a form's clean() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057252/django-how-do-i-access-the-request-object-or-any-other-variable-in-a-forms-clea)

Except, I have the same problem with admin form. So I can't see a way to init the form myself, therefore - to pass a request to it.

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

***Indeed, there is a way to solve your issue!***

You will need to [subclass form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6062628/497056) provided by `ModelAdmin.get_form()` and override it:

```
class BusinessDocumentCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        # Voila, now you can access request anywhere in your form methods by using self.request!
        super(BusinessDocumentCommentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.request.GET.get('document_pk', False):
            #Do something
    def clean(self):
        # Do something with self.request
        # etc.    
    class Meta:
        model = BusinessDocumentComment

class BusinessDocumentCommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    form = BusinessDocumentCommentForm     

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):

        AdminForm = super(BusinessDocumentCommentAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

        class AdminFormWithRequest(AdminForm):
            def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
                kwargs['request'] = request
                return AdminForm(*args, **kwargs)

        return AdminFormWithRequest
```

Comment: This is a great way to solve this! However, I'm a little confused about your usage of the term 'MetaClass' here. As I see it, ModelFormMetaClass is just a superclass of your form. What am I missing here?

Comment: @mkoistinen, you are absolutely right. This thought occurred to me some time in the past, but I was too lazy to correct the answer. Since people are still using the snippet, I have responsibility to correct it. Thanks for feedback. :-)

Comment: Thanks for updating, and, I got it wrong in my comment above. Its a *subclass*. Oops!

Comment: So this one creates a new class for every call of get_form? ISTR that class objects are never freed during a Python process lifetime. If true, then this solution is a memory leak…

Comment: The method get_form does not exist anymore in django >= 1.11

Comment: @melbic I see it here in 3.0: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form

Comment: This is great!. I hope Django support this requirement natively.

Answer (score 2):

This solution works for me. You can use `self.request` anywhere in the form to use it, including `def clean(self)`

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyForm

    def get_form(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, *args, **kwargs)
        form.request = request
        return form
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of hooks in the `ModelAdmin` class to allow you to do things this - look at the code in `django.contrib.admin.options`.

Two methods that might help you are `ModelAdmin.save_form` and `ModelAdmin.save_model`, both of which are passed the request object. So you can override these methods in your Admin subclass and do any extra processing you need.

**Edited after comment**

You're quite right that this won't let you validate the form dependent on the user's privileges. Unfortunately the form instantiation is buried deep within the `add_view` and `change_view` methods of `ModelAdmin`.

There aren't many possibilities without duplicating a lot of existing code. You could override the `*_view` methods; or you could try and override the `modelform_factory` function to return a new class with the request object baked in already; or you could try fiddling with the form class `__new__` method to do the same thing, but that's tricky because of the form metaclass.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for your answer! Actually, I've tried overriding these methods, berfore implementing forms... But - us I understood (from one of your answers, if I'm not mistaking) there is no way to perform validation from these methods. By "validation", I mean ability not to save some content if I don't like something and at the same time ability to give some valuable feedback. My task is - validation of admin input depending on user rights. May be I'm digging in a wrong place?

Comment: See my extended answer above.