# Django Error on custom admin form while attempting to get session

Tags: python, django, admin

Whenever I try to access my form in the admin page I get the following error.

**TypeError at /admin/scoring/score/add/
super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type**

at the line

```
AdminForm = super(ScoreForm, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

I am trying to access the session during form initialization so I can persist what was selected in the menu widget throughout the length of the session. I am following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683689/django-access-request-object-from-admins-form-clean). I can not find what I am doing wrong.

```
class ScoreForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    super(ScoreForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)

    standard_events = Event.objects.filter(event_score_type='STD')
    event_widget = self.fields['event'].widget

    choices = []
    for element in standard_events:
        choices.append((element.id, element.name))
    event_widget.choices = choices

def clean_score(self):
    print self.request.session
    print(self.cleaned_data['event'])
    selected_event = Event.objects.get(name=self.cleaned_data['event'])
    if(selected_event.max_score > selected_event.min_score):
        if self.cleaned_data['score'] < 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Score Cannot Be Negative")
        elif self.cleaned_data['score'] > selected_event.max_score:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Score Cannot Be Greater Than Best Possible Score of " + str(selected_event.max_score))
        elif self.cleaned_data['score'] < selected_event.min_score:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Score Cannot Be Less Than Worst Possible Score of " + str(selected_event.min_score))
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['score']
    elif selected_event.max_score < selected_event.min_score:
        if self.cleaned_data['score'] < 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Score Cannot Be Negative")
        elif self.cleaned_data['score'] < selected_event.max_score:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Score Cannot Be Less Than Best Possible Score of " + str(selected_event.max_score))
        elif self.cleaned_data['score'] > selected_event.min_score:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Score Cannot Be Greater Than Worst Possible Score of " + str(selected_event.min_score))
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['score']
    class Meta:
        model = Score


class ScoreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ScoreForm

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):

        #Line Below Causes Error
        AdminForm = super(ScoreForm, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

        class ModelFormMetaClass(AdminForm):
            def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
                kwargs['request'] = request
                return AdminForm(*args, **kwargs)

        return ModelFormMetaClass
```

Comment: your trying to get the super() of ScoreForm, but the object is admin.ModelAdmin, not ScoreForm.

Comment: I tried changing the erroneous line to `AdminForm = super(admin.ModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)` but now I get _'super' object has no attribute 'get_form'_ when I know get_from exists.

Comment: it seems in your example that get_form() is a method of ScoreAdmin, which looks recursive.  Where is get_form() method you want to call defined?

Comment: I want to use super to call the original get_form() method in admin.ModelAdmin.

Comment: did you try, super(ScoreAdmin, self).get_form(...)?