# django admin - get_language is getting default language, not active one

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a custom admin form validation js code in separate js file.

i want to render the appropriate js file, meaning if `LANGUAGE_CODE` is `'es'` , the js file should end with `myjsfile_es.js`

I did:

```
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Media:
       js = ('js/custom_%s.js' % get_language(),)
```

the actual page's url is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/es/admin/blog/blog/add/
```

but `get_language` is giving `'en'` so I end up having wrong js file `custom_en.js` for `es` page,

`en` is default language in settings.py.

how can I get the active language in admin.py?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is because django get's your language from the browser settings. I had same issue in one of my projects, and solve it by using that middleware:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


class IgnoreAcceptLanguageMiddleware(object):
   """
   Ignore Accept-Language HTTP headers

   """

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.META.has_key('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'):
            del request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']
```

Comment: why are you deleting ``HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE``, I need it in other places, I just need an access to request object in admin.py

Comment: Sorry this is another issue, misunderstand you question. There is a lot of answers for your problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683689/django-access-request-object-from-admins-form-clean

Answer (score -1):

you can get the current language from `django.utils.translation.get_language()`

Check documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/#using-translations-outside-views-and-templates

Comment: please read my question, this is exactly what is not working for me

Comment: That's weird behavior of django. There are two additional methods regarding get_language. May be they help 'get_language_from_path', 'get_language_from_request',

Comment: yeah, but the other two methods need a path or request object which i dont know how to get in admin.py