# how to override django admin form Foreignkey based on request.user

Tags: python, django, django-1.3

---

## admin.py

```
class PromoAdmin(admin.modelAdmin)
      list_display = ( 'name', 'id', 'category', 'promo_type', 'store', 'brand', 'date_start' )
      form = SampleForm
```

## forms.py

```
class SampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
     model = Promo

def __init__(self, request *args, **kwargs):
    super(PromoAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields["store"].queryset = Store.objects.filter(onwer=request.user)
```

got an error on request

Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
**init**() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Explain what is the error that you got?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initiate the store field with request.user in the field declaration. You can try the following:

```
class MyAwesomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    store = forms.ModelChoiceField(Store.objects)
    class Meta:
       model = Promo

def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyAwesomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['store'].queryset = Store.objects.filter(owner=user)
```

While instantiating the form you can pass the request.user object.

```
myform = MyAwesomeForm(request.user)
```

If you want to achieve this in the admin you might try [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.queryset)
For providing only the objects related to the logged-in user in the admin provides the possibility to overwrite ModelAdmin.queryset function:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyAwesomeAdminForm()
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(store__owner=request.user)

class MyAwesomeAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Promo
```

Note that store__owner only works if you have a foreign key field stored in your promo model as such:

```
class Promo(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)

class Store(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I assume it should also be possible to somehow pass the request to the init method of the form. But did not find a suitable approach to do it.

Comment: thanks for answering tom, followup question, this form will be use in the django admin. So we will override the the admin form. How do i pass request.user

Comment: I got reference to solve this problem https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey

Comment: this is better if you need request in admin model form class-> http://stackoverflow.com/a/6062628/758202