# Django. 'request' object is None in ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I want to override the bahaviour of *saveas* button - i need after pushing it to redirecrt me not in list of objects, but in a new object directly.

So i need to override the standart **save** method of *ModelForm* and get in there the **request** object - to check if *saveas* button was pressed:

```
*admin.py
class AirplanesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AirplaneEditForm


forms.py
class AirplaneEditForm(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    super(AirplaneEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def clean(self):
    print self.request
    return self.cleaned_data

def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True,):
    plane = super(AirplaneEditForm, self).save(commit=False)

    print self.request

    if commit:
        plane.save()

    return plane

class Meta:
    model = Airplanes
```

But in both *prints* request is **None**... Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: You need to pass `request` explicitly in init, which is not done by model admin.

Comment: can you write a code example please ? I try to do that, but Django tolds me, that he don't know the **request** object in admin.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django forms are something between models and views, which means they are context-agnostic. You generally should not do things that depend on `request` objects inside your form.

What @Rohan means is that `AirplanesAdmin` does not pass in request objects when your form is initialized, so when you `kwargs.pop('request', None)` the is actually an internal `KeyError` and the default value (the second argument, `None`) is returned. Nothing is really popped from `kwargs`. To override this behavior, you will need to override rendering methods of `ModelAdmin`.

Read [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods) for methods you can use.

Comment: Looked at the docs, the **save_model** method solved all my problems. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Request object is not being passed to forms.py from admin.py

So, in admin.py:

```
class AirplanesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AirplaneEditForm(request=request)
```

See another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1057640/1526703)

Comment: Um. `AirplaneEditForm(request=request)` uses the value of `request` (if any) at the moment of _class definition_.

Comment: I think you are right @tzot. Perhaps I'll just delete my answer