# how to access uploaded file list in django forms.py

Tags: django, django-forms

how can i in Django access uploaded file list (multi file upload) in forms.py.

In a view i access file list like this :

```
request.FILES.getlist('files')
```

but in forms.py i get this error:

```
Exception Value:    'UploadForm' object has no attribute 'request'
```

i tried solution in this [address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057252/how-do-i-access-the-request-object-or-any-other-variable-in-a-forms-clean-met) but i get error when using this code :

```
def clean_files(self):
    data = self.request.FILES
```

**error**:

```
Exception Value:    

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'FILES'
```

Comment: The request object is not available in the context of the form by default. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057252/how-do-i-access-the-request-object-or-any-other-variable-in-a-forms-clean-met

Comment: as i said above i did that but i get this error :`
Exception Value:  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'FILES'`

Comment: You first need to understand why that is happening. Then everything will make sense. `self.request` would be None, and you are trying to access `FILES` from there. Did you try and understand the answer provided in that link ?