# Django forms - displaying fields based on request parameter

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

i' ve the following django model:

```
class OrderLog(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    entry = models.TextField()
    private = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and the related form:

```
class OrderLogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderLog
        fields = ('entry', 'order', 'private')
```

. How can i modify the fields parameter based on the request parameter? So, if the user is testuser, than the fields tuple contains only the first 2 elements, in other cases 3 elements. Can request be accessible somehow from the form itself?

Thanks.

Comment: U might want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057252/how-do-i-access-the-request-object-or-any-other-variable-in-a-forms-clean-met

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to pass only the object you need (in this case `request.user`) rather than passing the entire `request` object.

Here is a possible solution:

```
class OrderLogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderLog
        fields = ('entry', 'order', 'private')

    user = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(OrderLogForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.user.username == 'testuser':
            del self.fields['private']
```

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite it in init like this:

```
class OrderLogForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # expects a request object to be passed in initially
        self.r  = kwargs.pop('request')
        super(FrageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    if 'value' in  self.r:
         self.fields["field1"] =  forms.CharField(initial=None)  
    else:
         self.fields["field1"] =  forms.CharField(initial=None)
         self.fields["field1"] =  forms.CharField(initial=None)
```

Comment: Passing the request parameter works fine, thanks, but setting the field does not really. If i try it within the init method, i got that the form does not have a fields attribute. If i try it outside of the init method, i got that self does not exists.

Comment: Ah, sorry, now it works, just can You please move the "if" section into the __init__ ?