# how get a variable from url to form's method - save?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-generic-views

I have urlpattern with id

```
...
url(r'^3/(?P<id>[-\w]+)', Biochemical_analysis_of_blood.as_view(),\
    name='biochemical_analysis_view'),
...
```

views.py

```
class Biochemical_analysis_of_blood(CreateView):
    model = BiochemicalAnalysisOfBlood
    form_class = BiochemicalAnalysisOfBloodForm
    template_name = "biochemical_analysis_of_blood.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("patients")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Biochemical_analysis_of_blood, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["patient"] = Patient.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['id'])
        context["caption"] = 'Біохімічний аналіз крові'
        context["new"] = True
        return context
```

forms.py

```
class SaveForms():
    def save(self, commit=True):
        analysis = Analyzes()
        sid = transaction.savepoint()
        analysis.name = self.data["name"]
        analysis.patient_id = Patient.objects.get(id=1)
        analysis.who_send = self.data["who_send"]
        analysis.who_is_doctor = self.data["who_is_doctor"]
        analysis.lab_user_id = Doctor.objects.get(id=self.data["lab_user_id"])
        analysis.additional_lab_user = self.data["lab_user_add"]
        analysis.date = self.data["date"]
        analysis.type = 3
        analysis.date_analysis = self.data["date_analysis"]
        analysis.save()
        # Your analysis is created, attach it to the form instance object
        self.instance.analysis_id = analysis.id
        return super().save(commit)
```

How I can get a variable "id" from url to form's method - save? class SaveForms will be inherethed by other forms.models classes because they all must have same save method.

```
...
    analysis.patient_id = Patient.objects.get(id=1)
...
```

Instead "1" I must use "id" from url...Who can help me, please?

```
class BiochemicalAnalysisOfBloodForm(SaveForms, forms.ModelForm):
...
```

Comment: Almost all of your save method is completely unnecessary. This is what Django modelforms do already.

Comment: For the rest, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user - it talks about request.user, but the principle is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acces the request data in your form, check this answer:

[How do I access the request object or any other variable in a form's clean() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057252/how-do-i-access-the-request-object-or-any-other-variable-in-a-forms-clean-met)

Instead of the request.user object take request.path.