# How to read session language in a class form __init__ function

Tags: python, django

in my Django project I dynamically create the fields of ContactsForm class:

```
class ContactsForm(forms.Form): 
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ContactsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['nome'].widget.attrs.update({
        'class' : 'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'your name *',
        'type': 'text'
        })
    [..]
```

In the template:

```
[..]    
#set language
<a href="/language/it">ITA</a> - <a href="/language/en">ENG</a>
{% if session_language == 'it' %}
   [..]
{% else %}
   [..]
{% endif %}
<form id="contactForm" name="sentMessage" method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
  [..]
  <div class="form-group" >
   {{ form.nome }}
  </div>
  [..]
</form>
```

How can I pass the `session_language` attribute to the ContactForm class so that I can use it as a flag to switch between the italian and english versions of the fields?

```
 if lang == 'it':
  self.fields['nome'].widget.attrs.update({
        'class' : 'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'il tuo nome *',
        'type': 'text'
        })
 else:
  self.fields['nome'].widget.attrs.update({
    'class' : 'form-control',
    'placeholder': 'your name *',
    'type': 'text'
    })
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

**EDIT**:
as soon as I posted the question I realised that I can simply make the template use a different ContactForm based on the value of `session_language`. In the views.py I can read the `request.session['lang']` and instantiate a different form based on the lang value.

In **views.py**

```
if request.session[`lang`] == 'it':
    form = ContactsForm()
else:
    form = ContactsForm_eng()
```

Is there any more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow the [access-the-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057252/how-do-i-access-the-request-object-or-any-other-variable-in-a-forms-clean-met)

you can try:

```
class ContactsForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(ContactsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.lang = None
        if self.request:
            self.lang = self.request.session.get('lang')
```

in view.py

```
 form = ContactsForm(request=self.request)
```

Comment: There really isn't `request` and nothing can be read from session. Any other suggestions?