# how to access session variable inside form class

Tags: django, django-forms

Hi i have a session variable city, how to access it inside form class.

Something like this

class LonginForm(forms.Form):

```
current_city=request.city
```

Comment: A `Form` has by default no access to the `request` object, but you can make a constructor that takes it into account, and processes it.

Comment: I did it in this way inside LoginForm

Comment: well of course in the view, you then need to construct it *with* the `request` object.

Comment: I did it in this way inside LoginForm
    class LonginForm(forms.Form):
        def __init__(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        super(LoginForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        current_city=request.city

when i do this i am getting this ERROR
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Comment: I will try and check

Answer (score 5):

A `Form` has by default no access to the `request` object, but you can make a constructor that takes it into account, and processes it. For example:

```
class LonginForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, request=None, **kwargs):
        super(LonginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.request = request  # perhaps you want to set the request in the Form
        if request is not None:
            current_city=request.city
```

In the related views, you then need to pass the request object, like:

```
def some_view(request):
    my_form = LonginForm(request=request)
    # ...
    # return Http Response
```

Or in a *class-based* view:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class LonginView(FormView):
    template_name = 'template.html'
    form_class = LonginForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(LonginView, self).get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs
```

Comment: I am working on the same but what how can I save it in the session? I am not able to access ```request.session['key']```

Comment: @Deshwal: `self.request.session['key'] = ...`? That being said, session variables should be used scarcely, especially since these are not persistent.

Comment: Can You help me out if I put another Question after some time. Would You please see it. Because it is a bit complex to people and they don't see it. I'll post a link to my question here. Would you please answer it?

Comment: Can you please tell me why [this form ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57830992/error-while-accessing-request-sessionkey-inside-forms-using-checkboxselect) is not working as expected?