# How to update widget attribute based on user role in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-permissions, django-widget

I have this custom widget:

```py
class RelatedFieldWidgetCanAdd(widgets.Select):

    def __init__(self, related_model, related_url=None, can_add_related=True, *args, **kw):
        self.can_add_related = can_add_related

        super(RelatedFieldWidgetCanAdd, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

        if not related_url:
            rel_to = related_model
            info = (rel_to._meta.app_label, rel_to._meta.object_name.lower())
            related_url = 'admin:%s_%s_add' % info

        # Be cautious, as "reverse" is not allowed here
        self.related_url = related_url

    def render(self, name, value, *args, **kwargs):
        self.related_url = reverse(self.related_url)
        output = [u'<div class="d-flex">']
        output.append(super(RelatedFieldWidgetCanAdd, self).render(name, value, *args, **kwargs))
        if self.can_add_related:
            output.append(u'<a href="%s?_to_field=id&_popup=1" class="add-another" id="add_id_%s" onclick="return showAddAnotherPopup(this);"> ' %
                        (self.related_url, name))
            output.append(u'<img src="%sadmin/img/icon-addlink.svg" width="20" height="50" class="pb-2 mx-2" alt="%s"/></a>' %
                        (settings.STATIC_URL, _('Add Another')))
        output.append(u'</div>')
        return mark_safe(u''.join(output))
```

And this is how I'm using it in **form.py**:

```py
class LeaveForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    leave_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=LeaveType.objects.all().order_by('-pk'), empty_label='--------',
        widget=RelatedFieldWidgetCanAdd(
            LeaveType,
            related_url='leave_type_add'
        )
    )
```

Now, if I'm logged in as a superuser in my dashboard, I can see the **+** button to create a related object. That's fine, but when I'm logged in as a normal user, it allows me to add related data. I know it's because I've set **`can_add_related`** to **`True`** by default. I want to update it while rendering it by checking the user's **`is_superuser`** or **`is_admin`** attribute. I tried to access the **Request** inside the widget, but I don't have access to the **Request** object. So, I can't do it in **`RelatedFieldWidgetCanAdd`**. There's a method named **`get_form`** that I tried to use for this, but it removes the **css** class and sets the **queryset** empty. Even if I provide all values again in **`get_form`**, it doesn't work. Is there any other simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement the `LeaveForm.__init__()` to receive a parameter `can_add_related` in your view and inject it into the widget.

Something like:

```
class LeaveForm(forms.ModelForm):
...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        can_add_related = kwargs.pop("can_add_related", False)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ... 
        self.fields["leave_type"].widget.can_add_related = can_add_related
```

In the view you call:

```
form = LeaveForm(..., can_add_related = request.user.is_superuser | request_user.is_admin)
```

Comment: Hello @Karsten Schulz, Thanks for your answer I did solved my problem in same way but instead of passing `can_add_related` in `LeaveForm.__init__`  I passed request object and then added condition for `request.user.is_superuser`  and for admin and set value for `can_add_related`

Comment: I got Idea from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1057640/14457833) but for this I've to pass request object in each views where I want to access it. I was looking for more dynamic way or a way where I don't want to change multiple file just one change in a file should reflect for all form widgets.